# Macro to copy paste 12 times repeatedly

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I wanted to create a macro to repeat the same paragraph 12 times and then move to the next one, repeat the above function till end of document.

I tried and now I want to create a loop for the below macro until the end of the document, so any help is highly appreciated:

```
Sub SelectRange()
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Paste
Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the MSDN documentation for [Paragraphs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837506.aspx) ... specifically paragraphs.range.text  and paragraphs.add

Comment: Ummm... What do you mean "until the end of the document"?  You realize the document gets a paragraph longer each time you paste the selection, right?

Comment: @Comintern..Yes i understand the purpose of doing it...the reason being instead of copy pasting one paragraph 12 times in document i wanted to create a macro which copies each para 12 times moves to next and then copies it 12 times again and then it goes on till all the paragraphs are copied 12 times ...any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: does the order of the paragraphs matter? You can copy the whole document and paste it 12 times

Comment: @Slai yes it does matters this is the reason i am asking for a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific problem I would use @Corith_Malin answer but wit a small tweak. You have to create a container for all the current paragraphs on the document (in this case I will use an ArrayList I create with late binding). After you have all the paragraphs on your container you can loop through them and paste them with the previously provided loop like so:

```
Sub SelectRange()

'Declaration and assignation of the ArrayList
Dim arrList as Object
Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'Loop through each paragraph and store it on the ArrayList
For Each par In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    arrList.Add (par)
Next

'Loop through each stored paragraph
For Each Item in arrList
    Item.Range.Copy

    'Loop 12 times and perform a paste operation
    For i = 1 To 12
        Selection.Paste
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Please test it and let me know your comments. It works on my computer (programmer joke ;) )

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for:). Thank you so much for making my life easier.

Comment: Excellent. Please accept the answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're just curious about how to use a loop instead of Selection.Paste 12 times...

```
Sub SelectRange()
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy

' Loop 12 times and perform a paste operation
For i = 1 To 12
  Selection.Paste
Next i

' You may need to set Count:=12 here to skip over the pasted content.
Selection.Next(Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: ..Thank you for the suggestion however what i was asking for is to create a loop in such a way that above code runs again and again till all the paragraphs are copied 12 times and i don't have to run again and again for all the paragraphs.